# await DisplayActionSheet(...) return null immediately

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I change the MainPage after run App.
After that any calls await DisplayActionSheet(...) and await DisplayAlert(...) return null immediately. But only on WindowsPhone.
Do You know right way to change MainPage?
The source with problem https://github.com/devcatch/MasterDetailAndActionSheet

Comment: Can you please share the code, what you have tried?

Comment: Added link to source

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that you would have to assign the response of the DisplayActionSheet to a variable before returning e.g.

Instead of:

```
return await DisplayActionSheet...
```

Use:

```
var response = await DisplayActionSheet...
return response;
```