# await DisplayActionSheet(…) return null immediately on Windows

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to display a MessageDialog from a ViewModel, and I need to associate an Action to the button pressed. For that purpose I've written the following:

```
//Dummy implementation
private string Translate(string element) => element;

public async Task ShowAsync(string message, Dictionary<string, Action> commands)
{
    var translatedCommands = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    foreach (var element in commands)
        translatedCommands.Add(Translate(element.Key), element.Value);

    string selectedElement = null;

    var buttons = new string[translatedCommands.Keys.Count];
    translatedCommands.Keys.CopyTo(buttons, 0);

    Task<string> Result = null;
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        Result = App.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(message, null, null, buttons);
    });

    selectedElement = await Result;
    if (selectedElement == null)
        return;

    translatedCommands[selectedElement]?.Invoke();
}
```

And then I call it from a RelayCommand

```
   private async void ExecuteButtonCommand(object p)
        {
            int Selectedindex = 0;

            var messageCommands = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
            {
                {  "Before 2003", () =>
                    {
                        Selectedindex = 1;
                    }
                },
                {  "After 2003", () =>
                    {
                        Selectedindex = 2;
                    }
                },
            };

            await ShowAsync("Select period", messageCommands);
            var dummy = Selectedindex;
        }
```

That works very well on Android but on Windows `DisplayActionSheet` return null immediately. I've seen [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630160/await-displayactionsheet-return-null-immediately) but it does'nt work for me because if I await inside `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` ShowAsync does'nt become awaitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found a solution.

On Windows (Phone) `DisplayActionSheet` should not be executed in the MainThread, but just awaited.

```
public async Task ShowAsync(string message, Dictionary<string, Action> commands)
{
    var translatedCommands = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    foreach (var element in commands)
        translatedCommands.Add(Translate(element.Key), element.Value);

    var buttons = new string[translatedCommands.Keys.Count];
    translatedCommands.Keys.CopyTo(buttons, 0);


    string selectedElement = null;

    if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
    {
        Task<string> Result = null;
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            Result = App.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(message, null, null, buttons);
        });

        selectedElement = await Result;
    }
    else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows || Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
    {
        selectedElement = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(message, null, null, buttons);
    }
    else
        throw new NotImplementedException("Only implemented for Android and Windows (Phone)");

    if (selectedElement == null)
        return;

    translatedCommands[selectedElement]?.Invoke();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that on Android, the `Action` in `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is executed immediately, and `Result` is assigned a value. On Windows, the `Action` may not be executing as soon as the `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` method is called.

You really shouldn't be doing a result dependent action on another thread, as you're doing here. Instead, you should either **wait for `Result` to be assigned** or **execute the latter part of `ShowAsync` on the Main Thread.**

I'd recommend the second option as you're not really doing anything else apart from consuming `Result` after it is assigned in the main thread:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    string selectedElement = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(message, null, null, buttons);
    if (selectedElement == null)
        return;

    translatedCommands[selectedElement]?.Invoke();
});
```

This, however, does not make `ShowAsync` asynchronous anymore. To make an asynchronous version of this method, simply extract the edited contents of `ShowAsync` into a synchronous `Show` method, and create an async wrapper:

```
private void Show(string message, Dictionary<string, Action> commands)
{
    // Code in ShowAsync is moved here
}

public Task ShowAsync(string message, Dictionary<string, Action> commands)
{
    return Task.Run(() => Show(message, commands));
}
```

Comment: Nope! It didn't work. The Show doesn't wait until the messagedialog is closed, and DisplayActionSheet doesn't wait. So my action isn't performed.